# Java windows app - is it possible to detect if the current device has touchscreen capability?

Tags: java, touch

As it says in the title, I have a Java app that runs on Windows (using SWT). How can the java app detect if the machine has touch screen capability?

The purpose is to present different UI elements if touch screen is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you could only use a function in User32, which is called GetSystemMetrics. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385(v=vs.85).aspx

There are many ways to get access to this library in Java. Although none of them looks pretty nice.